# Writing CASE Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to display two columns in a report,whose values will be determined using the same input expression as following:

```
SELECT     
CASE WHEN id>10

THEN 'AAAA'
 ELSE 
  'BBBB' 
 END as 'FirstColumn',  

CASE WHEN id>10

THEN 
  'BBBB' 
ELSE 
  'DDDD' END as 'SecondColumn'
```

Can I construct this expression without  repeating input expression twice as they are same?

Comment: What do you mean by "input expression"? This isn't a standard piece of SQL terminology, and made me think you were referring to a parameterised expression in your query (which isn't present in your query).

Comment: indeed it is: http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/case.html

Comment: microsoft uses "input expression" also : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: The Microsoft article uses "input expression" to mean "expression that has been entered into this function", while the SmallSQL article uses "input expression" to mean "expression that has been entered into this case condition". In neither case does the presence of that phrase on a SQL-related piece of documentation signify that it is a standard piece of SQL terminology - it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to repeat the CASE statment for each field as while the condition might be the same teh results are differnt.  The only other alternative is to use a UNion all statement whenre the first select takes the records WHERE id<=10 and the other one does the WHERE ID>10. This can bea viable alternative but it is a littel hareder to maintain, so if the performance is good enough, Iwoudl stick to repeating teh CASE condition.

Answer (score 1):

If some sophisticated is supposed instead of `id>10` then, to make it a bit shorter and a bit more readable:

```
select
  IIF(p.b=1, 'AAA', 'BBB') [Col1],
  IIF(p.b=1, 'BBB', 'DDD') [Col2]
from
  TableName t
  outer apply (select cast(case when t.id>10 then 1 else NULL end as bit) as b) p
```

However, this is only available in SqlServer 2012. In earlier versions, parhaps, you will have to write your own IIF-like scalar function:

```
create function dbo.IIF (@b bit, @ifValue varchar(50), @elseValue varchar(50))
returns varchar(50)
as begin
  return (select case when @b = 1 then @ifValue else @elseValue end)
end
GO

select
  dbo.IIF(p.b, 'AAA', 'BBB') [Col1],
  dbo.IIF(p.b, 'BBB', 'DDD') [Col2]
from
  TableName t
  outer apply (select cast(case when t.id>10 then 1 else NULL end as bit) as b) p
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's worth the trouble, you could created a User-defined function (UDF) that would do this transforamation logic:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fColTransform(@id Int)
     RETURNS Varchar(20)
 AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret Varchar(20)

    SET @ret = 
       CASE 
          WHEN @id IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
          WHEN @id > 10 THEN 'BBB'
          ELSE 'DDD'
       END
    RETURN @ret
 END
```

Then, in your SELECT,  you could structure it like this:

```
 SELECT dbo.fColTransform(id1) AS FirstColumn,
        dbo.fColTransform(id2) AS SecondColumn
  FROM MyTable
```

Comment: But in the Funtion also I have to write expression twice as my condition is constant but the result varries for different column.

Comment: Then you're actually executing different logic for each column.  That's kind of hard to abstract.   Depending on how many times  you use it, you can pass in the "less than 10" and "greater  than 10" values as additional parameters.   It won't save you time, but it might enhance your code readability.    If you do this, you'd call it like `SELECT dbo.fColTransform(id1, 'AAA', 'BBB')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a variable and use `Execute` to call it:

```
Declare @foo as nvarchar(max)
set @foo='MyTable'
execute ('Select * from ' + @foo)
```

The downside is that your entire query would be all red (since it's now a string).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query, maybe will be useful (in the case if you do not use a function):

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT     
    CASE WHEN x.ID > 10
      THEN 'AAAA'
      ELSE 'BBBB' 
    END as Col
  FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT 11 AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT 13 AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT 9 AS ID
        UNION
        SELECT 7 AS ID  
  ) x
)
SELECT temp.Col AS  FirstColumn, temp.Col AS SecondColumn 
FROM temp
```

Basically:

```
With name As (
     /*yourquery with one CASE-COLUMN*/
)
SELECT name.COL AS COLUMN1, name.COL AS COLUMN2 FROM name
```

You can try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17759)